# responsive footer and google maps

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

If anyone has some time to spare I'd realy apreciate if someone looked at my code and helped me out...

While creating a footer for my web page (I'm making it with Bootstrap) i encountered a problem that i can't solve on my own... **I read a few post on here and googled the problem** and **found some solutions** but they **dont work in my case...**

The problem is with the google maps inside **iframe** element... while the page is loaded on a computer monitor jumps to left corner and covers all other content... but it somehow works on mobile...

And here is my code:

```css
#noga {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #002d68;
  position: relative;
  font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}

#noga .contacts {
  width: 100%;
}

#noga .contacts .title {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

#noga .footer-columns {
  display: inline-flex;
  list-style: none;
  padding-top: 10px;
}

#noga .tekmovanja {
  list-style: none;
}

#noga .tekmovanja a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 200;
}

#noga .osnovni-podatki {
  list-style: none;
}

#noga .osnovni-podatki a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 200;
}

#noga .povezave {
  list-style: none;
}

#noga .povezave a {
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 200;
}

#noga .mnz .logo {}

#noga .mnz .detail {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 200;
}

#noga .map {
  margin-left: 25px;
}

#noga .iframe {
  margin-bottom: -5px !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<section id="noga">
  <div class="contacts">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-1 footer-columns">
          <ul class="tekmovanja col-md-2">
            <div class="title">Tekmovanja:</div>
            <li><a href="#">3.SNL - Sever</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1. Članska liga</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2. članska liga</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pokal člani</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mladina</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Pokal mladinci</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Kadeti</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Starejši dečki 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Starejši dečki 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mlajši dečki 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mlajši dečki 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Mlajši dečki 3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Starejši cicibani A+B</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Starejši cicibani A-1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Starejši cicibani A-2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Starejši cicibani Koroške</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Zimska liga</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Futsal</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="osnovni-podatki col-md-2">
            <div class="title">Osnovni podatki:</div>
            <li><a href="#">Klubi</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Reprezentance</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Grassroots</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Klub Klubu</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Obrazci in predpisi</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Trenerji in sodniki</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Delegati</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Razno</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Ugodnosti</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="povezave col-md-2">
            <div class="title">Povezave:</div>
            <li><a href="#">Nogometna zveza slovenije</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MNZ Lendava</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MNZ Murska Sobota</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MNZ Ptuj</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MNZ Celje</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MNZ Gorenjske</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MNZ Ljubljana</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MN Koper</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">MNZ Nova Gorica</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Rad igram nogomet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">As v nogah</a></li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="mnz col-md-2">
            <div class="logo">
              <img src="img/logo.png" alt="logo" class="img-responsive" style="height:60px;">
            </div>
            </br>
            <p class="detail"><b>Medobčinska nogometna</br> zveza Maribor</b></p>
            <p class="detail">Engelsova ulica 6 </br>2000 Maribor</p>
            <p class="detail"><b>T</b>:031 782 191</br><b>E</b>:info@mnzveza-mb.si</p>
            <p class="detail"><b>Uradne ure:</b></br>pon.-pet. od 9.00 do 15. ure</p>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="map">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d1757.7189717539436!2d15.629256882849571!3d46.55027815580515!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x476f77bd9e426903%3A0xd89f34403b107bf0!2sEngelsova+ulica+6%2C+2000+Maribor!5e1!3m2!1ssl!2ssi!4v1497338864036"
          width="600" height="380" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

I would realy apreciate some help with this since im new to bootstrap :)

**P.S.** Sory for bad english, it's not my native language...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this closer to what you are after?
https://codepen.io/panchroma/pen/OgjpOB

Your original grid layout had the footer ul links on one row, and the map on a second row. You'll see that I commented out lines 65,66,67 and 69 to bring all the footer elements into the same row.

HTML is now

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-1 footer-columns">
            <ul class="tekmovanja col-md-2">
            ...
            </ul>
            <ul class="osnovni-podatki col-md-2">
            ..
            </ul>
            <ul class="povezave col-md-2">
            ..
            </ul>
            <ul class="mnz col-md-2">
            ..
            </ul>
        </div> <!-- end col-md-8 -->  

    <div class="map">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <iframe .... >  
        </div> <!-- end col-md-2 -->   
    </div> <!-- end row -->  
</div> <!-- end container-fluid -->
```

You might to also want to checkout the [documentation for nested Bootstrap columns](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-nesting), note that if you want the nested columns to take up the full width of their parent cell ...

> Nested rows should include a set of columns that add up to 12

Good luck!

Comment: yes, thank you mysterious stranger from the internet :D
now just how do I bring the map closer to these columns? there is a huge gap between them

Comment: @weinde, the gap you mention is related to the nested row detail that I noted. In the footer the col-md-8 has 4 nested columns. Try changing them all to col-md-3 (so that the sum of these nested columns is 12)

Answer (score 0):

See if this piece of html code help you out:

```
<section id="noga">
        <div class="container-fluid contacts">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-lg-12">
                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                                <div class="title">Tekmovanja:</div>
                                <ul class="tekmovanja">
                                    <li><a href="#">3.SNL - Sever</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">1. Članska liga</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">2. članska liga</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Pokal člani</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Mladina</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Pokal mladinci</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Kadeti</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Starejši dečki 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Starejši dečki 2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Mlajši dečki 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Mlajši dečki 2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Mlajši dečki 3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Starejši cicibani A+B</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Starejši cicibani A-1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Starejši cicibani A-2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Starejši cicibani Koroške</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Zimska liga</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Futsal</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                                <div class="title">Tekmovanja:</div>
                                <ul class="tekmovanja">
                                    <li><a href="#">3.SNL - Sever</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">1. Članska liga</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">2. članska liga</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Pokal člani</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Mladina</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Pokal mladinci</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Kadeti</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Starejši dečki 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Starejši dečki 2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Mlajši dečki 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Mlajši dečki 2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Mlajši dečki 3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Starejši cicibani A+B</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Starejši cicibani A-1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Starejši cicibani A-2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Starejši cicibani Koroške</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Zimska liga</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Futsal</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                                <div class="title">Tekmovanja:</div>
                                <ul class="tekmovanja">
                                    <li><a href="#">3.SNL - Sever</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">1. Članska liga</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">2. članska liga</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Pokal člani</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Mladina</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Pokal mladinci</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Kadeti</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Starejši dečki 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Starejši dečki 2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Mlajši dečki 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Mlajši dečki 2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Mlajši dečki 3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Starejši cicibani A+B</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Starejši cicibani A-1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Starejši cicibani A-2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Starejši cicibani Koroške</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Zimska liga</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Futsal</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3">
                                <div class="title">Tekmovanja:</div>
                                <ul class="tekmovanja">
                                    <li><a href="#">3.SNL - Sever</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">1. Članska liga</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">2. članska liga</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Pokal člani</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Mladina</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Pokal mladinci</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Kadeti</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Starejši dečki 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Starejši dečki 2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Mlajši dečki 1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Mlajši dečki 2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Mlajši dečki 3</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Starejši cicibani A+B</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Starejši cicibani A-1</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Starejši cicibani A-2</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Starejši cicibani Koroške</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Zimska liga</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="#">Futsal</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>

                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                            <div class="map">
                                <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d1757.7189717539436!2d15.629256882849571!3d46.55027815580515!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x476f77bd9e426903%3A0xd89f34403b107bf0!2sEngelsova+ulica+6%2C+2000+Maribor!5e1!3m2!1ssl!2ssi!4v1497338864036" width="100%" height="380" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

**Change your content and classes according to your requirements.**

Comment: Please try to give hints next time instead of just giving out a possible solution directly. This approach does not help the other person understand the underlying causes of the problem better.

Comment: sorry but your solution is not what i'm looking for... it completly screws up the layout of elements...
but thank you for taking your time and helping me :)

Comment: I tried my best to solve your problem .. thank you for appreciating :) weinde

Comment: Next time I will take care of it..  @nclandrei